# How to completelly remove Ranger Admin Server and Ranger KMS from the Ambari 2.3 cluster

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have added Ranger Service (Ranger Admin Server, Ranger Usersync, and Ranger KMS) to the existing Ambari 2.3 cluster (4 nodes), running on the Ubuntu 14.04 Servers. All services are on the Master Node. However, it doesn't installed correctly and now it shows 'Install Failed' on the left hand side column of available Services on the Main Ambari page, and I believe this is what puting the Master node down. I can't find any option available to Delete the Service on the Ambari Web UI. I followed [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Using+APIs+to+delete+a+service+or+all+host+components+on+a+host) tutorial, but without success. Every time I try to delete whole service with the following command
 `curl -u admin:admin -X DELETE  http://AMBARI_SERVER_HOST:8080/api/v1/clusters/c1/services/SERVICENAME` it ends up with an error: "400"... something...

> you need to add "X-Requested-By ... "

So my commands according to our system was:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X  "X-Requested-By: ambari" DELETE  http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/cluster1/services/ranger
```

Also I've tried:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X  "X-Requested-By: ambari" DELETE  http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/cluster1/services/rangeradmin
```

And finally:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X  "X-Requested-By: ambari" DELETE  http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/cluster1/services/RangerAdmin
```

My thoughts is that as far as these services were not installed properly, the system can't see them. Or maybe some other issues..
However, I still cannot figure out what the actual command is, and is it possible at all to remove the service?!? I know I can hide this issue, with the 'Turn On Maintanace Mode' as option, and in that case Master Node will run as normal, but I want to completelly get rid of this Service, as I don't need it anymore. Any help appriciated, as I spent half a day trying to remove it, with no success.

Answer (score 4):

sorted. if anyone interesting to delete Ambari services (in my case it was a RANGER) from the command line, run the following:

```
    // get the service
curl -u admin:admin -X GET  http://HOST_NAME:8080/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTER_NAME/services/RANGER

// stop the service
curl -u admin:admin -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X PUT -d '{"RequestInfo":{"context":"Stop Service"},"Body":{"ServiceInfo":{"state":"INSTALLED"}}}' http://HOST_NAME:8080/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTER_NAME/services/RANGER

// delete the service
curl -u admin:admin -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X DELETE http://HOST_NAME:8080/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTER_NAME/services/RANGER
```

P.S. Simply put your hostname instead of HOST_NAME and your cluster name instead CLUSTER_NAME
Hope it helps anyone with the same issues.